# Get element by name, on duplicate get first value only

Tags: jquery

I understand how to get an element using the name attribute.  I wish to get the value of an input of a given name, and if there are more than one inputs, just get the first one.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myName" value="first" />
<input type="hidden" name="myName" value="second" />

var myVal=$('[name="myName"]').val();  //should be "first"
```

Comment: That's what `.val()` does.

Comment: It says it in the first line of the documentation: _Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements_

Comment: @Barmar Wasn't sure about "or set the value of every matched element."

Comment: It only sets the value when you give two arguments.

Comment: Given the three answers, looks like others are a bit confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition with length

```
if($("[name='myName']").length > 1){

 var myVal= $("[name='myName']").eq(0).val(); // first

}
```

Comment: This check is not needed as val() returns the first element in the set anyway.

Comment: No, Check condition be safe

Comment: Why does checking make it safer?

Comment: @JqueryKing, what I am referrring to is `.eq(0)`. Calling `val()` gets the first, so specifying `eq(0)` is un-needed unless you can explain otherwise while I am not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector :

```
var myVal=$('[name="myName"]:first').val();  //should be "first"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myVal=$('[name="myName"]:first-child').val();
```

Use CSS3 pseudo classes to get the first element if there are more elements than one.

Comment: What makes you think the first input is also the first child of its parent element?